# If sets A and B have an infimum, and A∩B≠∅ , then A∩B has an infimum.

Tags: real-analysis

I am certain that this is true, since any sets apart from irrationals have infimums, but I'm not sure how to prove it. I know that sets A and B are from R real numbers, and therefore they have infimums. Any intersection taken from those two would have a range of values, and regardless of whether they have closed or open brackets, it would have an infimum, but I have no idea how to mathematically prove this.

Comment: Are $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: "any sets apart from irrationals have infimums" is not true.  For example, the integers do not have a (real) infimum.

Comment: Yes, both A, B⊆R

Answer (score 1):

Say $x\in A\cap B$. Then $\inf A \leq x$. So $A\cap B$ has a lower bound, hence it has an infimum.